# pass parameters to php method using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am just wondering, is there a way to pass the parameters to php method from an ajax call? This is what I had in mind but it does not work.

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "?do=saverates",
    data: {"siteId": siteId, "portId": portId},
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,

    success: function(jsonObj) {}

  });
```

php method:

```
public function saveRates($siteId, $portId){

   echo "$siteId : $portId";
}
```

Comment: the line url:"?do=saverates is missing the ending quote?

Comment: and the success-function is not closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deal with the in PHP the same way as you deal with any data from an HTTP request.

```
$_POST['siteId']
```

etc.

Comment: I am not worried about how you normally do it, I can make it work by calling $_POST in the php method but I just wanted to know if I could pass parameters to a parameterized method without using $_POST. I would really like to reuse an existing method that has parameters.

Comment: You can't directly call PHP **methods** over HTTP at all. You make an HTTP request to a script. That script reads `$_POST` and calls the method you want with the arguments extracted from the POST data.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I wanted to know is if it could be done. This marked my curiosity a while back and never could find anything related to my answer.

Comment: You *could* achieve something like what you want, but for security reasons and the way you'd have to use PHP - you wouldn't want dynamic parameter names and values for your functions.

Answer (score -1):

"?do=saverates" is not a url. try something like "mycontroller/mymethod"

Comment: this url works, this is just how we have our controller structured.

Comment: "?do=saverates" **is** a URL, even though relative URIs consisting of just a query string are unusual and even though using a query string on the URI of a POST request is also unusual.

Comment: I agree however I cannot argue about what is already developed an put out live.